# Parameters of ajax request don't change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modx

I' m using cms ModX and want to send Ajax request to server using post method. The problem is that  the post data of the second, the third and so one requests doesn't  change and remains the same as in the first request.

To clarify the situation I provide the following example.

The javascript is the following:

```
var reqCount = 0;       
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function() {   

    var dataToPost = {'reqCount' :reqCount};
    $.ajax({
        url:  'http://example.com/ajaxTest',    
        method: 'POST',
        data: dataToPost,
        dataType:"json",
        success:  function(data){

            ajaxCountFromServer = data['ajaxCount'];

            reqCount=reqCount+1;
            }

        });
     }

}
```

Also I created resource with address http://example.com/ajaxTest in Modx with the code, running the snippet:

```
[[getAJAX]]
```

**getAJAX** snippet is the following:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {

       $reqCount = $_REQUEST['reqCount'];

       $json_obj = array("ajaxCount" =>$reqCount);
       return json_encode($json_obj);
    }
?>
```

So, after the first scroll **reqCount**=0, it's passed to server and after the server responses(success callback) **ajaxCountFromServer**=0 and **reqCount**=1. There all works well.

However, after the second scroll **reqCount**=1 and after the server response **ajaxCountFromServer**=0,but it should be 1.

How to fix it?

Comment: well did you check that `dataToPost` contains increased value each increase? If it does not, then try to make `reqCount` global (assight without var)

Comment: yes, I use Chrome debugger and watch it. In fact, `reqCount` is global. I delete var and it doesn't help.

Comment: Your snippet call is cached. `[[!getAJAX]]` - this is right calling.

Comment: After using `[[!getAJAX]]` the server returns empty string in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. In the page customizing of the resource http://example.com/ajaxTest,  where snippet **getAJAX** is called,  I just unchecked the checkbox "Cacheable".

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is

```
[[!getAJAX]]
```

The snippet is not cached now